# FCM MessagingOptions restrictedPackageName implementation

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have 2 Android apps in one Firebase project container, the first app has FCM implementation on Cloud Function and it works well, but the second app will received this notification as well so using `restricted_package_name` in messaging option is what we are looking for. However the question is, do we need to update the app as well or just the function in Cloud Function? Thus everything related to filtering of push notif. will be handled by its API and all we need is to provide the package name for the target app.

According to documentation of **restrictedPackageName**

> The package name of the application which the registration tokens must match in order to receive the message.

Do we need to handle token as well? Do we need to update the code in the app or just add the option in the function with NodeJs?

```
    const options = { priority: 'high' };

exports.announcement = functions.firestore.document("Announcement/{doc_id}").onCreate((added) => {

    const title = added.data().title;
    const description = added.data().description;
    const bigImage = added.data().bigImage;
    const link = added.data().link;
    const environment = added.data().environment;

    const payload = {
        data: {
            title: title,
            description: description,
            bigImage: bigImage,
            link: link,
            environment: environment,
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Announcement", payload, options)
        .then(val => {
            console.log("Success!\n" + JSON.stringify(payload), val);
            return true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Failed to send notification.", error);
            return true;
        });

});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the cloud function which you are using and also if possible, part of the code where you implemented ?

Answer (score -1):

From Firebase side it is not recommended to use same project for 2 different applications, which was also mentioned in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html). If you want to use `restricted_package_name` you need to update the code so that the object sends it in notification. You can find a small [example here](https://github.com/appfeel/node-pushnotifications).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor good day first, the question is about Android not a NodeJs app so the sample is not relevant to the question. Second I never read any word "not recommended" on the given blog, neither in any Firebase article and SO question I read so far, I forgot to mention that these apps is the same and all we want to know is whether we need to change only the Cloud Functions or the app code as well. Third you revised the question which is totally not readable and can result to more confusion.